# How to select all initialization cells?

Tags: front-end

Is there an easy way to select all initialization cells (and only those) in a Mathematica notebook?

Comment: If you just need to evaluate the initialization cells, this can be done via the Evaluation menu -> Evaluate Initialization Cells, or programmatically using `FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["EvaluateInitialization"]]`.

Comment: @dws: Yes, that I know (and that's the main reason why I use them to begin with). However, every now and them I want to copy all the initialization cells (which due to my working style tend to be scattered throughout the notebook) into a fresh notebook (simply because the current notebook gets too large). And I'd like to avoid the tedious work of going through the notebook and looking for initialization cells.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My method is to define a special style in stylesheet for initialization cells. Here is my definition:

```
Cell[StyleData["Initial"],
 CellFrame->{{1, 1}, {1, 1}},
 CellMargins->{{78, 10}, {5, 10}},
 Evaluatable->True,
 CellGroupingRules->"InputGrouping",
 TextClipboardType->"InputText",
 StripStyleOnPaste->True,
 PageBreakWithin->False,
 GroupPageBreakWithin->False,
 InitializationCell->True,
 DefaultFormatType->DefaultInputFormatType,
 ShowAutoStyles->True,
 "TwoByteSyntaxCharacterAutoReplacement"->True,
 HyphenationOptions->{"HyphenationCharacter"->"\[Continuation]"},
 AutoItalicWords->{},
 LanguageCategory->"Mathematica",
 FormatType->InputForm,
 NumberMarks->True,
 LinebreakAdjustments->{0.85, 2, 10, 0, 1},
 CounterIncrements->"Input",
 MenuCommandKey->"i",
 FontWeight->"Bold",
 Background->RGBColor[1., 1., 0.8666666666666667]]
```

Then you can use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd> to insert an initialization cell / convert an existing cell to `Initial`-style, and use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>left-click</kbd> to select all cells of this style in current notebook.

Comment: That's an interesting solution, but, as far as I can see, unfortunately not practical for my case because I often decide whether a cell should be an initialization cell *after* I created it. That is, I create the cell normally, and then later if I notice that I use the definition again farther away, I change it to an initialization cell.

Comment: It's what I did. I write codes in normal `Input`-style cells, and later select some of them and press alt+i to convert to `Initial`-style. This style definition is no more than just a wrap on a `Input`-style.

Comment: Ah, OK, then I misunderstood you. In that case, it indeed looks like a solution. How exactly do I add it to my default style?

Comment: You can edit the `Default.nb` file, but it would be more safe to create an individual style definition file, from the `Format` menu -> `Edit stylesheet`, create a new style with your preferred name, say `Initial`, select the cell and press alt+shift+E, replace the content in the cell with the above code. Use "save as" to save the stylesheet file to hard disk. From `Palettes` menu -> `install palette` to install it to your stylesheet menu.

Comment: I don't see an option "create a new style". I get a line "Private style definitions for (current notebook name)", a dropdownlist "Choose a Style" with the only option "All", followed by "or Enter a style name" followed by an input box and an "Install Stylesheet" button. And below a large area with the text `Inheriting base definitions from "Default.nb"` on the top. So where do I create the new style?

Comment: Input your new style name in the input box followed by "Enter a style name" and press enter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4427/discussion-between-silvia-and-celtschk)

Comment: Unfortunately the chat doesn't seem to work with this browser, but anyway, with your latest comment I managed to get it done, thank you very much. Works great!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Comment: Small note: new styles can inherit options from old styles. In this case, inheriting from the "Input" style may be desirable with `StyleData["Initial", StyleDefinitions->StyleData["Input"]]`. This makes cleaner and clearer definitions most of the time.

Comment: Unfortunately I just noticed a problem: As soon as I select the new stylesheet, all the standard styles (Title etc.) disappear. The new "Initial" style is the *only* one available. What might I have done wrong?

Comment: @celtschk The first cell in your stylesheet should say something like "Inheriting base definitions from stylesheet "Default.nb" ". Perhaps you deleted that cell?

Comment: @dws +1, Your way is the standard method. I copied details from the `core.nb` stylesheet file for more customizable.

Comment: @dws: No, that cell is still there. However I notice that it is slightly more indented than the new cell. I have no idea why, or if that could be the reason for the problem.

Comment: @celtschk press ctrl + shift + E, see is the content `Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]]`?

Comment: @celtschk If the first cell contains the contents given by Silvia, I don't know what happened. You can start over with the default stylesheet from the Format menu. Then edit the (private) stylesheet and just copy-paste Silvia's code there below the "Inheriting..." cell. Say ok when MMA asks whether to interpret this. This should add the new style. Finally, you can save and install the stylesheet as described above.

Comment: I'm now at home, therefore I no longer can interact with the front end. However the saved style file has as first non-comment lines: `Notebook[{
Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],

Cell[StyleData["Initial"],` so that's probably OK. Further tests will have to wait for tomorrow. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @celtschk It should be OK then. You're always welcome.

Comment: There is already a `Code` style that is an initialization cell. That has particular styling that may not appeal but in that case `StyleDefinitions->StyleData["Code"]` probably makes more sense (?)

Comment: +1 Fighting the perennial underutilization of the stylesheets

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch AHA! You're absolutely right! I never used `Code` and completely forgot it's initialization style! You should post it as an answer :) Always forget things orz

Comment: @Rojo Thanks. I really want to learn deeply on the stylesheets things..

Comment: @Silvia I would have posted a stylesheet type answer based on the conversation thread -- as Rojo says stylesheets seem to be underutilized, however it seems to me the question is simply how to select all initialization cells and you can do that with keystrokes as per the last sentence of your answer.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a method that can be run on existing notebooks, but has some drawbacks.

It leverages the Evaluate Initialization Cells option by redefining `$Pre` to set the `CellTags`  then `NotebookFind` will select all the initialization cells.

First, we have a function that will set the `CellTags` of a cell when it is evaluated.

```
tagFun[input_] := (SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], All, EvaluationCell,
    AutoScroll -> False]; 
  SetOptions[NotebookSelection[], CellTags -> "init"]; 
  SelectionMove[InputNotebook[], After, Cell, AutoScroll -> False]; 
  input)
```

Then, change `$Pre` and evaluate only initialization cells.

```
oldpre = $Pre;
    $Pre = tagFun;
FrontEndExecute[FrontEndToken["EvaluateInitialization"]];
```

Finally, change `$Pre` back and select the initialization cells.

```
$Pre = oldpre;
NotebookFind[InputNotebook[], "init", All, CellTags]
```

The drawbacks are:

- I could not package this into a function. In fact, the commands apparently need to be in separate cells (as I have them here).
- This evaluates the initialization cells when run.
- Overwrites `CellTags` on initialization cells

Comment: An interesting solution, definitely worth having around, although for new notebooks Silvia's solution is superior.

Comment: @celtschk I agree. Too bad `NotebookFind` doesn't let you search cell options.

Comment: +1, for an existing nb you would like to scan your cells programmaticly.

Comment: +1. A consolation prize would be to use `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], CellEvaluationFunction]` instead of `$Pre`

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple of new V9 approaches that use `Cells`.  I think the `Cells` function makes some of these kinds of tasks simpler.

---

The first solution achieves the goal mentioned in a comment: How to copy all the initialization cells.

```
nb = EvaluationNotebook[]; (* change as desired *)
CopyToClipboard @ 
  NotebookRead @ Select[Cells[nb], CurrentValue[#, InitializationCell] &]
```

The cells may be pasted in another notebook.  The `Cells` approach allows one to do many things with cells, even if they are not actually selected in the notebook.

---

This creates a palette that allows you to mover a slider to select each initialization cell in turn.  It won't select all of them as asked for, but one can locate them, which sometimes I want to do. (Thanks to @CarlWoll for suggesting an improvement.)

```
CreatePalette @ Manipulate[
  initcells = Pick[#, CurrentValue[#, InitializationCell]] &@ Cells[SelectedNotebook[]];
  whichCell = Clip[whichCell, {0, Length[initcells]}];
  If[whichCell > 0, SelectionMove[#[[whichCell]], All, Cell] &@initcells];
  whichCell,

  {whichCell, 0, Length[initcells], 1},
  {{initcells, {}}, None},
  TrackedSymbols :> {whichCell}
  ]
```

Comment: Faster is to use `Pick[Cells[], CurrentValue[Cells[], InitializationCell]]` instead of `Select`.

Comment: @CarlWoll Thanks, again. I usually use `Pick`, but I probably didn't realize `CuurentVallue` would be "listable" in this context and didn't think the performance difference would be significant.

Comment: This doesn't show the located cell if it is within some section. But one can open all subgroups before.