# How to search for initialization cells?

Tags: initialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select all initialization cells?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9217/how-to-select-all-initialization-cells)

Is there an easy way to search for initialization cells or have all of them removed at once?

Comment: This can be done programmatically but I am sensing you mean by keystrokes or some kind of menu etc.? Can you elaborate.

Comment: Hi @2013 I mean sometimes I forget where I placed the initialization cells and not sure how to search and remove them if needed. Yes, keystrokes or menu would be nice.

Comment: This question is closely related to [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9217/how-to-select-all-initialization-cells)