# How can I jump to the next initialization cell?

Tags: front-end, customization, cells, keyboard, initialization

I've got a long document and I <s>suspect</s> know that I mistakenly set some cell in the middle of the document to be an initialization cell, probably hidden inside multiple collapsed sections and subsections.

Is there some keyboard shortcut, menu item, or front end token that will take me to the next initialization cell in the notebook?

Comment: In version 11, initialization cells have a grey background.

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm currently using v10, but I'm more concerned with situations where there are multiple collapsed sections and subsections and it would take a significant amount of time (including e.g. waiting for the front end to display graphics) to look for a gray background by opening and closing cell groups.

Comment: Strongly related answer (see solution at the bottom): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29242/280

Answer (score 3):

```
Select[Cells[], CurrentValue[#, InitializationCell] &]
```

You can use `SelectionMove` or just click on those objects to go there.

And here is a palette:

```
CreatePalette[

 Button[
  "To the next initialization cell",
  With[{nb = InputNotebook[]},
   While[
    SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell, AutoScroll -> False];
    Not@Or[
      First[SelectedCells[nb]] === Last@Cells[nb]
      ,
      CurrentValue[NotebookSelection[nb], InitializationCell]
      ]
    ];
   SelectionMove[nb, All, Cell];

   ],
  Method -> "Queued",
  FrameMargins -> 15
  ]
 ]
```