# How to automatically jump to the next input cell (instead of text cell) after evaluation?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, cells, customization

Per the advice at this [question about jumping to next input cell](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/29396/how-to-make-cursor-jump-automatically-to-next-input-cell-after-evaluating-previo), I added the code

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  CellEpilog :> SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], Next, Cell]
]
```

to my initialization block. However, this sends me to the next cell on <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of the next input cell. Since the notebook is a demonstration file for class, there is a text cell between each pair of input cells. Is there a way to jump to the next input cell instead of next cell.

Comment: related: [How can I jump to the next initialization cell?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136617/5478)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have relatively little experience with notebook programming, so this might not be foolproof. It worked in the few situations I tried.

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
  CellEpilog :> SelectionMove[NextCell[CellStyle -> "Input"], All, Cell]
]
```

Comment: I used this command in my initialization cells of several notebooks written by different authors, and it does exactly what I want.  Thanks.